# Sleeping a thread blocks the browser completely after 5 requests

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat, threadpool

I've got a problem with my app -- I am trying to implement long polling by listening for an internal request to be completed and got this piece of code below.

The issue I've got is that it blocks only after 5 requests from one client (mobile device), releasing after 60 seconds which seems to be the default session timeout. It works fine from a different client, but again, only 5 requests.

How can I solve this problem?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poll/{id}/{prop}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Response poll(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String prop){

        GameWrapper gameWrapper = GameRegistry.getById(id);
        PollRequest request = new PollRequest(gameWrapper, prop);

        request.listen();

        while(true){
            if(request.isCompleted()){
                return new SimpleObjectResponse(
                        SimpleObjectResponse.STATUS_SUCCESS,
                        gameWrapper.getGame()
                );
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: I've added whole method, hope that helps. PollRequest is a simple listener which watches a property of the GameWrapper being changed by a separate request. When it detects that, it sets itself as "completed"

**Edit**: I am using Tomcat 7 with Spring MVC 3, I've also tried running this on Jetty and reimplemented in Play Framework, same thing. I've increased thread number in Tomcat, but this doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Hard to answer without more details.  I'd recommend that you debug the application or add `System.out.println(...)` or other log statements to see where your program is getting hung up.

Comment: why don't you use synchronize?

Comment: Use asynchronous processing. Sleeping a worker thread is the worst thing you could do.